# Compilation Error when incrementing on a razor View

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, for-loop, razor

I am trying to increment on a razor View but "Count" is giving me the below error, I have added `@using System.Linq;` but I am still getting the same error. Please Assist.
Compiler Error Message:

> CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'int'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Number.Count(); i++)
{
    var item = Model.Number[i];
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Number, new 
    { 
        htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } 
    })                            
}


    /// <summary>
    ///  Number
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your `Model.Number` type is `integer` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Show us your model please

Comment: @YongShun it is integer

Comment: you cannot iterate on an integer. It is a single value. It's value would always be 1. `Count()` only works on collections. On things, that you can actually count.

Comment: Integer cannot use .Count(), only IEnumerable support for [`.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Take note that `Model.Number[i]` this will hit error as well. As you mention it (`Model.Number`) is an integer.

Comment: @Marco I have updated the question with the model, do I need to change my model?

Comment: So you put a range of numbers in your model and simply want to loop over all your numbers and print them as form-controls, yes?

Comment: What does the @model directive on top of your view say? `@model IEnumerable<int>`?

Comment: @YongShun Yes it is hitting the error, Should I change the model from being Integer?

Comment: @M-Fulu Be so kind and edit your question, with your goal: What is it, what you are trying to do. We can explain in detail, why it is happening, but we cannot tell you how to solve your problem, because we do not know your intention. Best thing we can do is guess.

Comment: @Marco what I am trying to do on the view is incrementing what ever the model returned by 1 and display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thank you everyone I managed to fix it by doing the following. there was no need for a for loop.

```
   var Number = Model.Number + 1;
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your model is like:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Number{get;set;}
}
```

And you want to display number+1,you can use:

```
@{Model.Number + 1}
```